# Conversion from DICOM to YUV file

Tags: matlab, dicom, yuv

I have a series of DICOM files that I loaded on matlab. I would need to create a YUV file from the DICOM slices.Does anybody know how to do so?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if this answers your question, but there is some code for this on the MATLAB file exchange:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11264-matlab-movie-to-yuv-file

I know this is for movies, but I think you will be able to use this code (maybe adapted) to run it for each slice separately, if that's what you want.